# Comment s’excuser de prononcer quelque chose mal ?

Tags: expressions, oral

Il serait très utile de connaitre quelques phrases par cœur pour s’excuser de sa mauvaise prononciation.  Pourriez-vous dire si les phrases ci-dessous sont à propos ? J’ai essayé de les mettre dans l’ordre croissant de gentillesse.

> Désolé de ma mauvaise prononciation.

Ou

> Je suis désolé de prononcer tout de travers / de buter sur des mots
>   tout le temps.

Ou

> Veuillez pardonner ma prononciation maladroite.

Connaissez-vous d’autres façons de dire qui traduisent la même pensée ? Je les lirais volontiers.

Answer (score 9):

Je dirais

> Excusez ma prononciation

qui a l'avantage d'être compréhensible, assez soutenu et simple à prononcer, ce qui est plutôt souhaitable pour ce genre de phrases.

Comment: Peut-être que ***Veuillez excuser ma prononciation*** sera moins agressif, moins péremptoire et ouvrira à la bienveillance de l'auditeur.

Comment: Merci pour avoir répondu. Au fait, il serait pratique de connaître une façon d’utiliser *prononcer* au lieu de *prononciation*, car ce premier mot se prononce plus facilement à mon avis. (C’est sauf quand l’emploi de *prononcer* entraine l’emploi d’autres mots que je trouve durs à prononcer.)

Answer (score 2):

Pour donner d'autres voies que celle (excellente) proposée par Evpok, et surtout *en évitant le terme **prononciation*** (qui est, en effet, plus difficile) comme semblait le vouloir Koenraad dans son commentaire :

> « Excusez-moi si je prononce mal » *(on conjugue le verbe pour ne pas utiliser le substantif, mais le sens est identique)*
>
> « Excusez mon accent » *(le sens est légèrement différent, bien sûr, et un accent n'est pas quelque chose dont on aurait à s'excuser, que ce soit clair, mais ça a le mérite d'être court, clair, et "assez" facile à dire)*
>
> « Je vais essayer de bien prononcer. » *(dite avec un sourire, cette phrase a le même effet performatif que des excuses préventives)*

A toi de faire quelques essais pour déterminer laquelle te vient le plus facilement.